# Python: есть ли библиотека для работы с точками эллиптической кривой?

Tags: python, математика, библиотеки, криптография

Добрый день!
Интересует, есть ли у Питона библиотека для работы с эллиптическими кривыми?
Конкретно интересуют функции наподобие:

- Умножение точек
- Сложение точек
- Удвоение точки
- Нахождение противоположной точки
- Принадлежность точки кривой
- <и т.д.>

Answer (score 1):

Все, что есть в библиотеках уже обернуто в высокоуровневые функции для работы с криптографией. Для кривых есть такой пример: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_arithmetic#Python Умножение, сложение и другие операции. Есть небольшое пояснение вверху страницы.